# $.ajax error getting back data from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a website, and right now the registration form of it! But I have something like a problem! I want to create a Username input field, and when the user is typing, check if the username already exists in the database and give some output.

The error is this one: suppose that in the database there is only the username "Manuel". If I type "Manuel" in the input field no message is shown. Now if I type any other character it gives me the message 'The user already exists'. If i delete the last typed character the message goes away. If I type again and have something like "Manuela", the message shows up, if I type again and have "Manuelae" the message goes away

Thanks for your help!!

Here the code

Here the input field: (register.php)

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="40" required="required">
<span id="username-info">What's your username?</span>
```

Here the javascript and jquery code (registration.js)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var userExists = new Boolean();

    var username = $("#username");
    var usernameInfo = $("#username-info");

    username.keyup(validateUsername);

}
```

Here the function validateUsername():

```js
function validateUsername(){
    checkUsername();
    var minlenght = 5;
    var usernameVal = username.val();
    if(usernameVal.length < 1){
        usernameInfo.addClass("input-error");
        usernameInfo.text(messages.FIELD_REQUIRED);
    }  else if(usernameVal.length < minlenght){
        usernameInfo.addClass("input-error");
        usernameInfo.text(messages.USERNAME_MIN_WORDS+minlenght+' '+messages.USERNAME_CHARACTERS);
    } else if(userExists){

        //here i tell the user that the user already exists
        usernameInfo.addClass("input-error");
        usernameInfo.text('The user already exists');

    } else {
        usernameInfo.removeClass("input-error");
        usernameInfo.text("");  
    }

}
```

And here the function checkUsername():

```js
function checkUsername() {
        var url = 'processregistration.inc.php'; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url: url,
            data: {username: username.val()},
            success: function(data){

                userExists = data.CHECK; //true if the user exists, false if not

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Use console.log() to show data sent and received. This can help to find error. By the way, shouldn't you call for show message when you get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax means **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML.

You are doing a check on a value which is actually not received.

You should do something like this :

```
function validateUsername() {
    // remove input-error, text

    if (...localcheck...) {
        // add input-error, text
    }
    else if (...otherlocalcheck...) {
        // add input-error, text
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success : function(data) {
                if (data.CHECK) {
                    // add input-error, text
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! i'm new here, how can i accept two answers?? both were useful :) and when i click +1 it says it needs +15 reputation and goes back to 0!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, but I don't think your implementation is correct.

*Note: I'm not a javascript hero*

```
$("#filter").keyup( function(e) {

var filter = $("#filter").val(),
    timer = $('#filter').data('timeout'),

if(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('#username').removeData('timeout');
}

$('#username').data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
    var url = 'processregistration.inc.php'; 

    $.POST(url, {username: $('#username').val()}, function(data) {
        // you get the picture ;)
        updateComponentThatShowsIfUserNameIsTakenFunction(data.CHECK);
    });
}, 100));   

function updateComponentThatShowsIfUserNameIsTakenFunction(taken) {
    $('#username').addClass('input_error');
}
```

What I did: Removed global variables, they are annoying and error prone. Instead, I'm using a callback named updateComponentThatShowsIfUserNameIsTakenFunction. You can also change it to directly call that function with the "data" of course. I have also added a timeout for you so that you won't call the server EVERY key-up. Every key-up cancels the previous timeout, causing the check to only trigger 100ms after the user is done typing (you don't want to spam your server).

I hope this works and helps you further!

Comment: There is some error in the code, exept the one when declaring variables :( i followed the tip of Smoky, but this thing of interval is very interesting! wouldn't it be the same thing using set interval function? setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType:"json",
     url: 'processregistration.inc.php',
     data: {username: username.val()},
     success: function(data){
      if(data.CHECK == true){
       usernameInfo.addClass("input-error");
       usernameInfo.text(messages.USERNAME_EXISTS);
       inputs[0]=0;
      } 
     }
    });
      }, 5000); //5 seconds

Comment: I would recommend to use $.POST to simplify things. It looks pretty much the same to me. I would also recommend to use less than 5 seconds, you don't want to user to wait about 5 seconds before the request starts. 100 ms is enough to prevent normal paced typers from spamming your server. If you want to play safe, put it to 250, which is 4x per second (which is already very slow).

Comment: i changed it a bit and it works fine!! Thanks very much! var globalTimeout = null; if (globalTimeout != null) {
    clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
     }
     globalTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    globalTimeout = null;  
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType:"json",
     url: 'processregistration.inc.php',
     data: {username: username.val()},
     success: function(data){
      if(data.CHECK == true){
       usernameInfo.addClass("input-error");
       usernameInfo.text(messages.USERNAME_EXISTS);
       inputs[0]=0;
      } 
     }
    });
     }, 100);